# what is wrong with my code for buttons

Tags: arduino-uno

```
int "buttons"[6];

int "buttons"[0] = 2;
```

When i upload the code to the board it says:

```
exit status 1
expected unqualified-id before string constant
```

Comment: please, take a coding course

Answer (score 2):

1. `"buttons"` is not a valid identifier (i.e., not a valid variable name) because it does not start with a letter or underscore.
2. You should not repeat the type when you want to refer to the already-declared variable.

You declare the variable like:

```
int buttons[6];  // A 6-element array of integers
```

And if you want to refer to a specific element in the array:

```
buttons[0] = 2; // Let the first element of the array be the value 2.
```